# CheckBoxTableCell select entire column

Tags: javafx-8

I can not get the value of the checkbox, whether it is selected or not. 
I can not select or deselect the entire column of CheckBoxTableCell

[image]

//CLASS MODELO

```
public class Cidade{

    private Integer codigo;
    private String descricao;

    public AAA(Integer codigo, String descricao) {
        super();
        this.codigo = codigo;
        this.descricao = descricao;
    }

    public Integer getCodigo() {
        return codigo;
    }

    public String getDescricao() {
        return descricao;
    }
}
```

//CREATION OF COLUMNS OF TABLEVIEW

```
TableView tbView = new TableView();
tbView.setEditable(true);

TableColumn colCheck = new TableColumn();
colCheck.setCellFactory(CheckBoxTableCell.forTableColumn(colCheck));

CheckBox cbk = new CheckBox();
cbk.selectedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {
    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable, Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (!tbView.getItems().isEmpty())
            if (newValue)
                for (int i = 0; i < tbView.getItems().size(); i++) {

                    ((CheckBox) ((TableColumn) tbView.getColumns().get(0)).getGraphic()).selectedProperty().get();
                }
    }
});

colCheck.setGraphic(cbk);

tbView.getColumns().add(colCheck);

TableColumn colCode = new TableColumn("Codido");
colCode.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("codigo"));

TableColumn colDescricao = new TableColumn("Descricao");
colCode.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("descricao"));

tbView.getColumns().addAll(colCode,colDescricao);
```

Comment: Do you have a `cellValueFactory` set for `colCheck`, in addition to the `cellFactory`? Without one, there is no `BooleanProperty` to which the check box is connected.

Comment: The problem is that the column colCheck is not a field of the city entity, it is only a help column to be able to select different cities, however if the entity had a boolean field everything was easier

Comment: You need *some* property to associate with the check box, whether it is part of the table's backing model or not. Otherwise, e.g. when a row is scrolled out of view the selected state of the check box will be lost entirely.

Comment: I found my solution here, thank you anyway          http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37334094/create-a-framework-type-column-header-for-select-all-in-javafx-8

Comment: Note that solution uses non-public API classes (at least in JavaFX 8). I added a solution which doesn't need a custom skin.

Answer (score 2):

The `CheckBoxTableCell` expects a `selectedStateCallback`, which is a function mapping the row index to an `ObservableValue<Boolean>` that determines if the check box should be checked. If the supplied observable value is also a `WritableValue<Boolean>`, then when the user checks or unchecks the check box, the value will be updated.

The simplest case for this is when the model for the table has a boolean property which is represented by the check box. However, this doesn't have to be the case. For example, you could create a map from your table items to a boolean property, and use the properties in that map for the selected state of the check boxes:

```
Map<T, BooleanProperty> checkedRows = new HashMap<>();


checkColumn.setCellFactory(CheckBoxTableCell.forTableColumn(i -> 
    checkedRows.computeIfAbsent(table.getItems().get(i), p -> new SimpleBooleanProperty())));
```

Here you would replace `T` with the actual type of your table.

You probably want to ensure the map doesn't hold references to items that are no longer part of your table:

```
// clear obsolete table items from map:
table.getItems().addListener((Change<? extends T> c) -> {
    if (c.wasRemoved()) {
        c.getRemoved().forEach(checkedRows::remove);
    }
});
```

Now you would just use the map to check for which items are checked:

```
T item = ... ;
boolean itemIsChecked = checkedRows.getOrDefault(item, new SimpleBooleanProperty(false)).get() ;
```

or get all the checked items with

```
List<T> checkedItems = checkedRows.entrySet().stream()
    .filter(e -> e.getValue().get())
    .map(Entry::getKey)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

You can select everything with

```
table.getItems().forEach(item -> 
    checkedRows.computeIfAbsent(item , item -> new SimpleBooleanProperty()).set(true));
```

and similarly deselect by setting to false.

Here is a complete SSCCE using the usual address book example:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.function.Function;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.BooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleBooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.collections.ListChangeListener.Change;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.CheckBoxTableCell;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TableViewWithCheckBoxColumn extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        TableView<Person> table = new TableView<>();
        table.setEditable(true);

        TableColumn<Person, Void> checkColumn = new TableColumn<>();
        table.getColumns().add(checkColumn);

        Map<Person, BooleanProperty> checkedRows = new HashMap<>();

        // clear obsolete table items from map:
        table.getItems().addListener((Change<? extends Person> c) -> {
            if (c.wasRemoved()) {
                c.getRemoved().forEach(checkedRows::remove);
            }
        });

        checkColumn.setCellFactory(CheckBoxTableCell.forTableColumn(i -> 
            checkedRows.computeIfAbsent(table.getItems().get(i), p -> new SimpleBooleanProperty())));

        CheckBox checkAll = new CheckBox();
        checkAll.setOnAction(e -> {
            if (checkAll.isSelected()) {
                table.getItems().forEach(p -> 
                    checkedRows.computeIfAbsent(p, person -> new SimpleBooleanProperty()).set(true));
            } else{
                checkedRows.values().stream().forEach(checked -> checked.set(false));
            }
        });

        checkColumn.setGraphic(checkAll);
        checkColumn.setEditable(true);

        table.getColumns().add(column("First Name", Person::firstNameProperty));
        table.getColumns().add(column("Last Name", Person::lastNameProperty));
        table.getColumns().add(column("Email", Person::emailProperty));

        table.getItems().addAll(
                new Person("Jacob", "Smith", "jacob.smith@example.com"),
                new Person("Isabella", "Johnson", "isabella.johnson@example.com"),
                new Person("Ethan", "Williams", "ethan.williams@example.com"),
                new Person("Emma", "Jones", "emma.jones@example.com"),
                new Person("Michael", "Brown", "michael.brown@example.com") 
        );

        Button verify = new Button("Verify");
        verify.setOnAction(evt -> {
            checkedRows.entrySet().stream().filter(e -> e.getValue().get()).map(Entry::getKey)
            .map(Person::getFirstName).forEach(System.out::println);
        });

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane(table);
        BorderPane.setAlignment(verify, Pos.CENTER);
        BorderPane.setMargin(verify, new Insets(5));
        root.setBottom(verify);

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 600, 600));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private static <S,T> TableColumn<S,T> column(String title, Function<S, ObservableValue<T>> property) {
        TableColumn<S,T> col = new TableColumn<>(title);
        col.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> property.apply(cellData.getValue()));
        return col ;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

with the usual `Person` model class:

```
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;

public class Person {

    private final StringProperty firstName = new SimpleStringProperty();
    private final StringProperty lastName = new SimpleStringProperty();
    private final StringProperty email = new SimpleStringProperty();

    public Person(String firstName, String lastName, String email) {
        setFirstName(firstName);
        setLastName(lastName);
        setEmail(email);
    }

    public final StringProperty firstNameProperty() {
        return this.firstName;
    }


    public final String getFirstName() {
        return this.firstNameProperty().get();
    }


    public final void setFirstName(final String firstName) {
        this.firstNameProperty().set(firstName);
    }


    public final StringProperty lastNameProperty() {
        return this.lastName;
    }


    public final String getLastName() {
        return this.lastNameProperty().get();
    }


    public final void setLastName(final String lastName) {
        this.lastNameProperty().set(lastName);
    }


    public final StringProperty emailProperty() {
        return this.email;
    }


    public final String getEmail() {
        return this.emailProperty().get();
    }


    public final void setEmail(final String email) {
        this.emailProperty().set(email);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks Sr. James_D for your answer, everything works fine, but in my case Map can not have a data type, I can not declare it Map <?, BooleanProperties> without a data type, so there is an error here

checkColumn.setCellFactory (CheckBoxTableCell.forTableColumn (i ->
CheckedRows.computeIfAbsent (tbView.getItems (). Get (i), p -> new SimpleBooleanProperty ())));

Comment: As you can see in the example I show I do not define any type of data for the TableView, only us with the type of data to which the columns will be associated or in this case Code and Description, but not the Class that will be associated with the TableView, only place the city entity to take as an example, but the TableView will show data from other entities that are going to have those two columns. If I would find a solution to my problem I would be very grateful. Again thank you very much.

Comment: "I do not define any type of data for the `TableView`": it is basically a mistake to do this, which is why I corrected it in my answer.

Comment: I understand, but to use the Map I need to declare it with a data type

Comment: Exactly. So declare your table with a data type too. As I said, using a raw type there is basically a mistake.

Comment: But that is my problem that not with us is the data type of my TableView and in this case will show different data of different entities, only that the entity associated with it has two fields one Code and another Description, that is why I define the two columns

Comment: I can't really understand that comment, but I think you are saying you want to reuse the table for different data types. I would recommend replacing the table view to display different data, instead.

Comment: That's what I'm talking about, and what you recommend to refresh my eyesight at what I do, by calling the TableView view that just shows data from a single entity, and does not show other data from another entity until do not be called again the view

Comment: Sorry, that comment is incomprehensible.

Comment: I'm going to explain myself better, in the commentary I was confirming what you had thought, that the TableView showed data of different entities, and also confirmed that I am refreshing the view of the TableView to display the data of another entity

Comment: The bottom line is: don't use raw types.

Comment: Though it's not actually clear why you couldn't just use a `Map<Object, BooleanProperty>`. And as I said, instead of "refreshing" the table view to display a different type of object, replace it entirely with a new table view, of the correct type.